# Как вызвать событие у импута type="number"?

Tags: php

Есть `<input type="number" name="amount">` цена + и - (и в поле "Всего" считается общая сумма)  Как получить событие при увеличении или уменьшении инпута? Что б я мог делать запрос и увеличивать цену в корзине.

Answer (score 0):

Самый очевидный вариант на кнопки "+" и "-" добавить onclick вызов функции умножения кол-ва товара из инпута на цену из блока, после обновлять значение блока суммы.

Answer (score 0):

HTML: `<input type="number" name="amount" class="amount_price_input">`

JS:

```
$(".amount_price_input").on('change',function(){
    $(".amount_price_total").html($(this).val().trim());
});
```

Пробуйте. Первая строка реагирует на изменения ввода суммы в поле, вторая помещает полученное значение в контейнер с общей суммой покупки.